# How to use apply function here?

Tags: python, apply, user-defined-functions

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

PATH = r'C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Net_Present_value.csv'

data1 = pd.read_csv(PATH)

def calc_equity(assets,liabilities):
    return liabilities - assets

data1.apply(calc_equity)
```

Its giving me error stating:

```
calc_equity() missing 1 required positional argument: 'liabilities
```

Please help as if how can I resolve this

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your data has two columns `['assets', 'liabilities']` and you want to calculate the equity as a third column. You don't need the `apply` function here. You can calculate it as a difference of the two columns:

```
data1['equity'] = calc_equity(data1['assets'], data1['liabilities'])
```

This would create new column `'equity'` in your DataFrame.

If you insist on applying a function to the DataFrame, the function in question needs to acept a single argument that is either a column or a row of the DataFrame. I  your case you want to take a difference of two values in the same row, so the function to apply needs to take a row as an argument:

```
def calc_equity(row):
    return row['liabilities'] - row['assets']

data['equity'] = data1.apply(calc_equity, axis=1)
```

`axis=1` tells the `apply` function to work on each row. In the function you can access the values in the row by the columns. Bear in mind that this is slower than the first approach as it iterates all the rows instead of working on the columns as numpy arrays.